# Every shell command in adb results in Aborted

Tags: android, shell, adb

I have some strange issue with my device.
it's connected through USB .

`adb devices` shows the device.
but every shell command I run results in Aborted.

for example

```
adb shell
shell@ja3g:/ $ input text try
input text try
Aborted
```

and nothing happens on the device.

any idea what am I missing?
I'm running API level 21.

Thanks

Comment: i also got same error for istall command("pm install -r xxxx.apk"). my device is gt-i9500/android 5.0.1/custom rom

Comment: @gturedi I'm using the same device , which custom Rom do you have?

Comment: Prism™ Barebone V15 yours?

Comment: Same one , there you go... this is probably the cause for our issue.

Comment: @RotemSlootzky I am having the same issue...any luck?  GS4 running GPE ROM http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2643031

Comment: did you guys get any fix. Im using Prism™ Barebone V15 and i cant be bothered to change it right now

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Turns out you have to set the proper environment variable for these commands to work

> export ANDROID_DATA=/data

just run the above command.